# How do call a Meteor server from an Ionic app and have it respect your user ID

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, angular-meteor

When I call try to call a Meteor server from an Ionic app, the user ID is not recognized on the server, despite having successfully logged in.

In the index.html of the Ionic app, before the meteor-client-side.bundle.js is included, the server URL is set:

```js
  SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:3000";  // Changes a lot. Run ipconfig. Look for Virtual Box???
  window.__meteor_runtime_config__ = {
       DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL: SERVER_URL,
       ACCOUNTS_CONNECTION_URL: SERVER_URL
  };
```

Then, the user logins which is successful and I Meteor.user() looks good.

```js
Meteor.loginWithPassword($scope.credentials.username,
                         $scope.credentials.password,
                         function (err) {
  if (err) {
    alert(err);
  } else {
    console.log('login success:' + JSON.stringify(Meteor.user()));
```

But, when the client code, tries to insert:

```js
self.addOwnedProduct = function () {
    var newOwnedProduct = {
      productID: "ZZZZZZ" + Math.random(),
      userID: Meteor.userId()
    };
    OwnedProducts.insert(newOwnedProduct);
};
```

The server code, sees the userId as null:

```
OwnedProducts = new Mongo.Collection("ownedProduct");
```

```js
OwnedProducts.allow({
  insert: function (userId, ownedProduct) {
    console.log("Meteor.isServer:" + Meteor.isServer);
    console.log("userId:" + userId);
    return true || (userId && ownedProduct.userID === userId);
  },
```

Here is a repo that replicates the problem

https://github.com/kokokenada/ionicToMeteorLogin

Comment: Please don't reference outside code. Please include all relevant code (and ideally only that) in the question itself.

Comment: I added the code as requested.  Is it OK to leave the reference to the repo in? If anyone wants to replicate the issue, it would save them time.

Comment: yes, this is perfect. thanks.

Comment: very strange. Does it work when you do not overwrite the `__meteor_runtime_config__`?

Comment: If I do not set  `__meteor_runtime_config__`, then it cannot find the server and the login fails. (Actually, login goes away and does not give the courtesy of a callback - but that's another issue...).  And I see `GET http://localhost:8101/sockjs/info?cb=tshtvxjwfv 404 (Not Found)` messages in the console. This makes sense as I am running the client with "ionic serve" which lives at localhost:8101.  The server for my Meteor app lives at localhost:3000.

Comment: what's `ionic serve`? "running the client"? meteor launches both the client and the server for you, and I'd imagine it has to. Can't you just use meteor-ionic?

Comment: AFAIK, "ionic serve" only serves the files that would normally packed into the Cordova app, so no real server features.  I might have to switch to running with Meteor CLI. Shockingly, it doesn't (didn't ?) support Windows.  Plus Ionic has some nice packaging service I might want to use.